# Sending email through Python with dual lan interface as fallback, why does the selected interface timeout unless both are active?

Tags: python, email, interface

Hope someone can help!

I'm fairly new at Python, so please excuse the code.
I have created a twisted webserver and have created a watchdog function to check and ensure the interface is available (in case the ethernet cable is unplugged). If the ethernet is unplugged it uses the wifi to send an email to alert one to the fact that there's an issue.

Here's the catch. The below code works fine on my test PC but somehow not on the server. When the backup interface is selected and tries to send an email it timesout - until both interfaces are active. On the test PC it works as expected (uses the backup interface, sends the email and waits until the ethernet / primary connection cable is restored).

Wireshark shows the correct interface is selected and retransmissions until timeout or the ethernet is restored and then sends the package/email.
Otherwise Python times out after a few seconds.

Ethernet interface is serving on 80 and 443. FWIW listening on these ports is active during the connectivity check.
Wifi when needed 587.

Actual error shown in Python - [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

```
    import smtplib
import ssl
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email import encoders



fromaddr = Sudo_address
password= SMTP_Password

msg = MIMEMultipart('related')

msg['From'] = SMTPReal_Email
msg['To'] = SMTPReal_Email

msg.preamble='This is a multi-part message in MIME format.'

msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

import time
DateStamp = time.asctime(time.localtime())
lt=DateStamp.split(" ")
if lt[2]=='':

    Logdate=lt[3]+" "+lt[1]
    Logtime=lt[4]
else:
    Logdate=lt[0]+", "+lt[2]+" "+lt[1]+", "+lt[4]
    Logtime=lt[3]

#status='up'


if status=='down':
    SubjectLine = "Webserver, URGENT - Webserver is DOWN @"+Logdate+", "+Logtime
    msg['Subject'] = SubjectLine 
    body="Hi Admin, <br><br>This is an <b>URGENT MESSAGE</b> - the webserver is down:<br><br>Date: <b>"+str(Logdate)+"</b><br><br>Time: <b>"+Logtime+"</b><br><br>Regards, <br><br>Admin"
else:
    SubjectLine = "Webserver, Server is RESTORED @"+Logdate+", "+Logtime
    msg['Subject'] = SubjectLine 
    body="Hi Admin, <br><br>This is an <b>important message</b> - the webserver service has been <b>RESTORED:</b><br><br>Date: <b>"+str(Logdate)+"</b><br><br>Time: <b>"+Logtime+"</b><br><br>Regards, <br><br>Admin"
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))


port = int(SMTP_Port)
smtp_server=SMTP_Server 
context = ssl.create_default_context()

from random import randint
sslSettings = ssl.SSLContext();
sslSettings.load_cert_chain(certfile="certificate.crt", keyfile="private.key")
    
tpport=randint(10000,65000)

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port,HostIP,context=sslSettings, source_address=(FallBackIPAddress, tpport)) as server:

        server.login(fromaddr, password)
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(fromaddr, SMTPReal_Email, text)
        
        server.quit()
```

The only difference perhaps that I can see might be the test PC (Python Libs) has been updated somewhere along the line, and maybe that's the issue?

Comment: the e-mail module won't know anything about network interfaces - you have to check the configuration and routing tables of your OS. The e-mail will do a DNS requests, then try a connection to whatever address it gets, on the appropriate ports - if both these connections are going through, it will work.

Comment: Thanks jsbueno, hadn't thought to check the routing. Will do so and revert back.

Answer (score 0):

JSbueno was right, the reason this didn't work is that the webserver (also the mail server) was set to send and receive on the same Lan connection for both html and SMTP. Rerouting mail to the secondary connection fixed the issue. Thanks jsbueno.